# Google App Engine: Deplying frontend and backend configuration (Nuxt + Django)

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, nuxt.js

I am deploying Nuxt (frontend, universal configuration), Django (backend API, DRF), and Postgres on Google App Engine and Cloud SQL.

If this is relevant: (I need to be able to store images, dynamically create and store new images and dynamically create and store pdfs.)

1. In Google App Engine, what is the ideal setup for Django and Nuxt in terms of speed and performance?
2. Should they be on separate apps?

Any information you can provide/suggest regarding this setup would be helpful as this is my first time deploying this configuration on GAE.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your App Engine environment is standard or flexible, you can use the following links to setup Django on the App Engine:

[1] Standard: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

[2] Flexible: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment